# Migrating to LinkedIn APIs V2 OR Updating LinkedIn permission settings

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

How do I edit App permissions for my current App, as there's no Edit option present  in the Linked Dashboard?

I would like to do this to give necessary permission for version 2.0 as r_basicprofile is now replaced by r_liteprofile which doesn't provide me with company positions.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: Facing the same issue here.. the sdk oauth flow seems to be failing due to this

Answer (score 0):

You can apply for partner program to use r_basicprofile  with V2 
but anyhow you have to migrate API 
because in V2 all API Url is change and also response is in different format 
Means using r_basicprofile with V1 and r_basicprofile with V2 both are different implementation

Comment: I am not using any marketing related permissions and hence applying to Partner program doesn't seem to be a solution.